# Asp.net Gridview - Why Are DataRowBound changes Lost on sort?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am making conditional formatting changes to the data in my gridview using a RowDataBound event:

```
    void gvReg_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {

          DateTime lastUpdate DateTime.Parse(DataBinder.Eval   (e.Row.DataItem, "LAST_UPDATE");

          if (lastUpdate < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1))
          {

             Hyperlink hypLastUpdate = (Hyperlink)e.Row.FindControl("hypLastUpdate";
             hypLastUpdate.CssClass = "Error";
             hypLastUpdate.NavigateUrl = "http://www.someExampleErrorPage.com";

          }

       }

    }
```

This works, and sets the proper CssClass to the hyperlink (which makes it a jarring shade of bold red), but once the gridview is sorted (via the user clicking a column heading) the css class is reset on hypLastUpdate and it loses both it's style and associated NavigateUrl property.

The control hypLastUpdate is contained in a template field in a gridview, and it's text value is databound to a field called "LAST_UPDATE".

Is this a planned behavior (is sorting supposed to break the conditional formatting done in RowDataBound events?) or is there something I can check to make sure I am not doing something incorrectly?

I am not using the DataBind method anywhere in the code behind, and viewstate is turned on for the gridview in question.

--EDIT--

It ended up being a mistake in event handling.

I was doing:

```
gvReg.Sorted += {SomeEventHandler}
```

Inside of the page load event, but only when it wasn't a postback.  This function called gvReg.DataBind after the grid view was sorted.  I removed the handler wire up and instead added the event handler function to the OnSorted event.  I guess assigned delegates to a gridview are not saved in ViewState between callbacks?

Comment: on grid view sorting event you need to rebind the data `gvReg.DataBind();`. so, this means you need to rebind your datasource with the data sorted(by sorting your dataset or requerying your database based on `pSortExpression = e.SortExpression;` and `pSortDirection = (pSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending);` on `protected void gvReg_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)` event so that `gvReg_RowDataBound` will be called again. you may need to check if `e.SortExpression.Length > 0` before doing this

Comment: @wllmsaccnt: Set a breakpoint in your RowDataBound event handler. Is this event handler being reached after sorting?

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: The RowDataBound is not being reached after the sorting occurs.  I even added a gridview.databind into the onsorted event, and it is still not being called.  Shouldn't the ViewState on my template field items save the conditional formatting after the RowDataBound event (such as after a sort operation)?

Comment: @wllmsaccnt: When a sort button is clicked there's a postback and the data is rebound to the grid. Consequently, the RowDataBound event handler should run after sorting. Can you share the markup for your GridView control in your question?

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: I don't think it is necessary to post the code at this point.  My RowDataBound handler was not being reached because it was only set to handle the event during the load event when it was not a postback (on first page view).  It was not remaining bound after subsequent postbacks.  I misunderstood the way that event handling works for ASP.NET, so it ended up being a rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: @wllmsaccnt: Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi here is a quick example of what I meant on my comment. This is the only way i could think of it:

```
    protected void gvReg_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;

        if (e.SortExpression.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataControlField field in gridView.Columns)
            {
                if (field.SortExpression == e.SortExpression)
                {
                    cellIndex = gridView.Columns.IndexOf(field);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (pSortExpression != e.SortExpression)
            {
                pSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                pSortDirection = (pSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending);
            }
            pSortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        }

        //Retrieve the table from the database 
        pSortOrder = pSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        List<Partners> partnerList = GetPartnerList();

        gvReg.DataSource = partnerList;
        gvReg.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: +1 for the response, but I don't think it is an answer (though I will mark it as one if I do not see additional answers).  My sorting is not provided by a sorting function.  I am using the built in sorting with an sqldatasource.